# What does mount mean in Flutter ? why is it used?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

```dart
void initUser() async {
    currentUser = await UserController.getUser();

    if (mounted) {
        setState(() => 0);
    }
}
```

What is this code doing? I've read the documentation but still couldn't understand.

What is this mounted keyword and what does it mean when we do `setState(() => 0)`? Does doing this set all the states to their initial values?

Comment: `mounted` seems to be a variable which has been defined ouside of the scope that you have provided. Where did you get the code from and can you provide more of it?

Answer (score 2):

`mounted` is the property of State. It sets to `true` when element of stateful widget adds to elements tree and sets to `false` when element removes from it. [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) to docs. [Link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-layer-cake-widgets-elements-renderobjects-7644c3142401) to useful article about trees.

What about your code, it is an error to call setState unless mounted is true. So `if (mounted)` is just for safety.